# Running a macro in current sheet and in all sheets after current one

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros, vba

I have a excel file, that has 12 sheets, each corresponding to a month. I have three macros that execute in a sheet they are run in. Is is possible to do it in a way, that if I run macro in sheet October, then it will also run in sheet November and December?

To put it more "mathematically". I have n sheets. I execute macro in sheet k (k > 0 && k <= n) and I want that same macro to execute in sheets < k+1, k+2, ... , n >.

Comment: Please tell us, in a non "mathematical" way, what you've tried so far. You said 3 macros on each sheet, then asked to run Octobers macro on November & December. Are the macros the same? Or do you mean to have October trigger the other macros?

Comment: Agree, it's not very clear. If you need the same macro to run, you just do `for ws` loop. If you need different macros to run then you need an `if sheetx then call` nest. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

1. `RunMacroOnAllSheetsToRight` loops through every sheet from the active sheet to the last sheet
2. For those sheets the function `MyFunction` is called which gets the sheet index as argument. The Msgbox is just an example action. Change it to your needs.

---

```
Sub RunMacroOnAllSheetsToRight()
    For i = ActiveSheet.Index To Sheets.Count
        Call MyFunction(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Function MyFunction(i)
    'Code goes here
    MsgBox "I'm currently on sheet " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
End Function
```